# Cómo validar y descargar un archivo .rar desde php

Tags: php, validación

Tengo una duda, estoy tratando de hacer una zona de descargas en mi página, pero no encuentro información que me sea útil o alguna explicación, ya que veo que ninguno valida.

Quiero que cuando el usuario le de click a mi botón de descargas pase dos cosas:

1)Que valide si le dio click a confirmar del recaptcha de google (este aún no lo he agregado al código ya que estoy configurando primero la descargas, así que pueden **IGNORAR** esta parte).

2)Que descargue.

El problema es que los códigos o explicaciones que encuentro, la mayoría dice que lo agregue a la etiqueta

```
   <a href="?p=descargar_depot&archivo=nombreArchivo.extension" download>
```

La ruta href la estoy poniendo adentro de la misma página. Este es mi código php:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['archivo'])){
if (!isset($_GET['archivo']) || empty($_GET['archivo'])) {
    exit();
}

$archivo = basename($_GET['archivo']);

$ruta = 'admin/download/'.$archivo;

if (is_file($ruta))
{
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$archivo);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($ruta));

    readfile($ruta);
}
else
    exit();
 }
 ?>
```

El problema esta es que con este código, luego de darle click al botón de "DESCARGAR" La página se queda pensando, luego se pone todo en blanco y deja de reaccionar; Así que tengo que cerrar la pestaña, pero no logra descargar.

¿Qué me recomiendan cambiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he desarrollado la lógica completa aún, pero básicamente logré que descargará, realice estas modificaciones:

1)A mi zona de descargas le agregue:

```
            <form method="POST" action="./api/download.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="ContenedorBotones">
                    <div class="informacion"><a href="?p=informacion">Más Información</a></div>
                    <button class="download" type="submit" name="Descargar" value="<?php echo $Rescatado['archivo']?>">Descargar!</button>
                    <div class="button">Captcha</div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

2)El documento que recibe esta información y descarga:

```
   <?php
   $filename = $_POST['Descargar'];
   $file = "./admin/download/";
   header("Content-Description: Descargar imagen");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
   header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
   header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   readfile($file);
   ?>
```

Esto ya me descarga el archivo que le estoy solicitando, aún le falta la validación, pero mi problema principal era que no descargaba. Debido a que la función **header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP.** Según la guía de PHP
**https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php**

Entonces, yo en la carpeta donde estaba pidiendo que me descargue el "X" documento, no me permitía debido a esta limitación de PHP, ya que yo tenía 1)include_once 'mi documento con el cabezal' y ese era el que me interfería el header() de php.

Espero mi solución y explicación le sirva a alguien más.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor solucion es crear un link directamente al archivo que se desea descargar de esta forma:
Muestras en enlace SOLO cuando el capcha sea true o este validado

```
<a <?="href='.$ruta.'"?> download target="_blank">Descarga</a>
```

A `$ruta` le indicas la ruta del archivo a descargar segun lo que seleccionen descargarse

Comment: El problema de eso es que no me valida, yo tengo en otro apartado así como me dices, pero yo necesito como dije, que valide 1)Que el usuario haga el captcha  y si eso está bien 2)Que descargue el archivo. El problema de <a href download> es que no tengo como comprobar si 1)Realizo el captcha y 2)Si realizo el captcha, que descargue

Comment: @AnthonyMelchor he editado la respuesta, pero te resumo, cuando el capcha este validado muestras el enlace pero con `target="_blank"`

Comment: Me parece buena tu idea, pero me piden que el usuario no haga tanto (por eso es que me estoy dando mala vida) Me piden que sea simplemente a dar click al recaptcha de google de ahí a descargar y que descargue. Creo que encontré como hacer esto, porque mi problema era con el header(), asi que le agregue a mi boton de descargas un `<form action="lance mi documento afuera de mi carpeta de vistas ya que este contenía mi header y eso generaba conflicto con el header() de php debido a que vi que el header() es algo 'sensible' ">`

Comment: Adjunto mi solución como respuesta, igual te doy las gracias por la idea amigo